# How to get web server to delete a file on the system after a period of time OR when they close the tab

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, tabs

People who use my website can grab videos from this certain school website, by submitting the link in a form. My web server then downloads it, and stores it in a folder so the person can download it.

I'm trying to figure out how I can get it to automatically delete the video file from the folder after a certain period of time (let's say 5 minutes), ***or*** if it detects that the user has closed the tab.

I don't really know where to start with this sort of thing, so can anyone please give me some guidance on how to do this? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cron Jobs to fulfill your task.

**What is a Cron Job?**

It is a Linux command that is used to schedule tasks from time to time. In this case, you can schedule your file deleting tasks there.

**How to create the function (overview)?**

In your case, you may need to maintain a DB Table that keeps the date that the user requested to download your file and any sort of other data like IDs. Then, you can create a function to loop through each table row and find files that need to be deleted. This can be done with an `if` clause. (if file date is greater than the current date). Then, delete the files as you need.

**How to schedule cron?**

This depends on the server Operating system and environment you use. I assume you use Linux. Then you have to run the below commands:

1. First visit crontab configuration file in your terminal :

`crontab –e`

2. Then add your cron job. Let's say you need to run your function every 5 minutes.

`5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /usr/local/bin/delete.php &> /dev/null`

Here, the first `5 * * * *` means that the cron job should run every 5 minutes. The second argument defines the PHP interpreter. In 3rd argument, it defines the file.

For more information on how to define cron jobs : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps